# R: How can I code repetitive output into an Rmarkdown file?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am doing complex exploratory analysis on a data set. I have created a function that will take the desired variables, run and evaluate several models then return a list with various results and plots. I can easily run this on the different combinations of predictor and outcome variables. I would also like to create a "function" or repeatable script that will display the results in the rmarkdown output, so I don't have to edit every chunk when I want to make a change to the output. (For instance, I just added a sensitivity analysis to the function, but now I have to edit about 45 chunks to get the results to display.)

**Simplified Example:**

```
#Packages used: dplyr, knitr, kableExtra, pander

data("airquality")
lm.1 <- lm(Solar.R ~ Wind, data = airquality, na.action = na.omit)
lm.2 <- lm(Solar.R ~ Wind + Temp, data = airquality, na.action = na.omit)

#The real output list is bigger/more complex:
myList <- list(model.1 = lm.1,  model.2 = lm.2, bic = BIC(lm.1,lm.2))


#Create a character vector containing each line of display code I wish to run:  

myDisplay <- c("kable('Model Comparisons', col.names = NULL) %>%
                  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = 'striped', font_size = 20)",
               "pander(myList$bic)",
               "kable('Full Model Summary', col.names = NULL) %>%
                  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = 'striped', font_size = 20)",
               "pander(myList$model.2)")
```

For each analysis output list I create, I want to run what is in `myDisplay`. So in the following chunks, I tried:

```
{r, eval = T, results = 'asis'} #I tried with and without "asis"
for(i in myDisplay){
  eval(parse(text = i))
}
```

When I run that for loop in the console, I get the expected outputs, but when I knit my rmarkdown file, I literally get nothing from it. No warnings, messages, errors, or anything at all.

Is there a way to do this? Does it have to do with `eval(parse(text = .))`? Is there something else to try?

**Post Script:**
@Aaron Montgomery's suggestion to add `cat(eval(parse(text=i)))` worked. There was one small problem with my real code. One of the list items was a plot returned by `ggplot()`. `cat()` could not handle that request. That's okay as it is easy to workaround.

My code chunks for each analysis now look something like this:

```
{r, results = 'asis'}
myList <- myFunction(X,Y,Z)
myList$plot
for(i in myDisplay){
  cat(eval(parse(text = i)))
}
```

Now I only have to edit `myFunction` and `myDisplay` to change the entire document.

Comment: Instead of `eval(parse(...))`, you can use `knitr::knit_child(text = i)`, and it'll return a `character` with rendered content that can be used directly (needs `results="asis"`, which you have).

Comment: @r2evans Thanks, but this returns "|||0%||...| 100% ordinary test without Rcode" for each i. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Not off-hand, but I haven't run full tests on this yet (busy with "work", sorry). BTW: `library(dplyr,tidyr,kableExtra,pander)` is incorrect syntax. It actually works a little for the second argument, but in reality this resolves to be `library(package="dplyr", help="tidyr", pos="kableExtra", lib.loc="pander")`, which is most likely not what you were intending.

Comment: @r2evans Yeah, I put that library call in there at the last minute just to acknowledge the packages I am using. Figured I'd get dinged for it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your `eval` in `cat()` (concatenate and print) to coax R to write something down:

```
{r, eval = T, results = 'asis'} #I tried with and without "asis"
for(i in myDisplay){
  cat(eval(parse(text = i)))
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try it: Error in cat(eval(parse(text = i))) : 
  argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'

Comment: That's... really, really weird. I was able to reproduce everything you described in the problem statement, but then this fix worked for me. https://www.dropbox.com/s/2aqbojh1714kxsz/knittest.html?dl=0

Comment: I'm trying it in my real data set, so maybe there is another issue. I'll look into it.

Comment: Yeah, I'd be curious to see if it works in your (very well-crafted) toy example. If so, that's probably illuminating.

Comment: I did work. The problem is that in my real output list, one of the list items is a ggplot2 plot. For some reason, cat() doesn't like that. But I took it out and it worked. I can easily work around this. The plot can be edited in the function. Thanks!